# Traefik v2 in Kubernetes. fail to deploy. do not see other services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, minikube, traefik-ingress

I have been trying to run traefik v2.x in minikube to check it and how it routes request to needed service. I am  failing to get access to my services at all. would be good to understand what I am doing wrong.

- minikube is running in VirtualBox VM
- VM box has lab IP address to which I want to send URL request
- on my localhost I set hosts (`mydomain.local` and `mydomain.com`) to IP address of minikube VM

[image]

How to reproduce:

1. create 2 namespaces `new-ns` and `new-who`
2. set namespace to be default for Ingress: `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=new-ns`

All yaml files can be found in https://github.com/vencrena-LT/traefik

3. deploy CustomResourceDefinition
4. deploy ClusterRole , ClusterRoleBinding and ServiceAccount (to new-ns namespace)
5. deploy DaemonSet and Service (to new-ns namespace)

then would like to deploy 2 apps: in both namespaces (for testing purposes)

1. Deployment, Service and IngressRoute to new-ns namespace
2. Deployment, Service and IngressRoute to new-new namespace

Dashboard:
[image]
Routes:
[image]
LocalPod:
[image]

some logs from traefik pod:

```
E0206 08:25:21.798628       1 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1alpha1.TLSStore: failed to list 
*v1alpha1.TLSStore: tlsstores.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:new-ns:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "tlsstores" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope

E0206 08:25:34.653633       1 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1alpha1.ServersTransport: failed to list
*v1alpha1.ServersTransport: serverstransports.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:new-ns:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "serverstransports" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope

E0206 08:26:02.857094       1 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1alpha1.IngressRouteUDP: failed to list
*v1alpha1.IngressRouteUDP: ingressrouteudps.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:new-ns:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressrouteudps" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
```

any **hints** what I am doing wrong? why can not access `mydomain.local` and `mydomain.com` and see whoami services. why no routes are seen in Traefik dashboard

Comment: Can you provide logs from `traefik` Pod ? Your `IngressRoute`s seem to be correct. Maybe it would be better for you to install `Traefik` using Helm Chart as described [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/install-traefik/#use-the-helm-chart) ?

Comment: I have no issues when deploying helm chart.  this is for learning and fully understanding how it should work.  good hint about logs - adding output to main question.  seems like service account does not have enough permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ClusterRole definition is a bit too thin:

https://github.com/vencrena-LT/traefik/blob/main/2_roles.yml

You could try to follow the example here:

https://github.com/sleighzy/k3s-traefik-v2-kubernetes-crd

For the question why no routes are seen:
Traefik will pickup from k8s routes when you specify

```
        - --providers.kubernetescrd
        - --providers.kubernetesingress
```

Also please be aware of the namespace where traefik resides, you will apply IngressRoutes on that namespace

Comment: @vencrena Does this answer your question ?